# Ruby on Rails - If statement using params - returning wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time getting something which should be incredibly simple to work.

I've got an online quiz with multiple choice questions and a pass/fail mark. I've got everything working correctly bar the damned emailer function at the end. No matter whether passed is set to true or false it's always sending out the passed email. Have I done something a bit daft in this code which I just can't see or am I going to have to go back through everything with a fine-tooth comb?

```
   def finalize
     quiztype = params[:quiztype]
     slug = params[:slug]
     @qd = Quizdata.where(quiztype: quiztype, usertoken: slug).take
     if @qd
       @qd.completed = true
       quizdata = JSON.parse(@qd.quizdata)
       quizdata["completed"] = true
       @qd.quizdata = quizdata.to_json
       @qd.passed = params[:passed]
       if @qd.save
         if params[:passed]
           QuizMailer.results_email_user(quizdata, @qd).deliver
         else
           QuizMailer.results_email_user_failed(quizdata, @qd).deliver
         end
         QuizMailer.results_email_client(quizdata, @qd).deliver
         render json: { errors: [] }
       else
         render :json => { :errors => @qd.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422 #Unprocessable entity
       end
     else
       render :json => { :errors => [ "Record not found" ] }, :status => 404
     end
   end
```

Comment: can you put `puts params.inspect` above the if condition, and let me know the output.

Comment: I, [2015-11-20T12:11:27.109689 #29542]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"correct"=>"4", "total"=>"22", "passed"=>"false", "quiztype"=>"mainquiz", "slug"=>"MjZlZDA1"} - thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Replace

```
if params[:passed]
```

with

```
if ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(params[:passed])
```

It was failing because, you are getting result in String format (not nil, which makes it return `true` always), instead of Boolean.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I got to the same thing at exactly the same time as you - this project has been never-ending - couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @MichaelSmith You can use the solution I provided instead of checking with `== "true"` if you are expecting variations in `:passed` values. This `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES` returns `{true, 1, "1", "t", "T", "true", "TRUE", "on", "ON"}`

Comment: That's really useful to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed as strings.

Should have been:

```
if params[:passed] == "true"
  QuizMailer.results_email_user(quizdata, @qd).deliver
else
  QuizMailer.results_email_user_failed(quizdata, @qd).deliver
end
```